# SciKit TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype(' u32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using the sklearn library with the following code, and get the error mentioned in the title. The code works if I uses non-linear classifiers (such as DecisionTreeClassifier or KNeighborsClassifier) but with linear_model classifiers like SGD and PassiveAggressive I get the error. I've tried mapping the array contents to floats but it does not work. All the contents of the array are 'numpy.unicode_'. I would appreciate help in resolving this issue.

The code:

```
from io import open
from os import listdir
import numpy as np

path = "address"
months = listdir(path)
for month in months:
    if "_sanitized" in month:
        files = listdir (path + month)
        for file in files:
            temp_path = path + month + "\\" + file
            text = open (temp_path, "r").read()
            lines = text.split("\n")
            attr_train = list()
            label_train = list()
            go = False
            for line in lines:
                if line != "" and not go:
                    row = line.split()
                    label_train.append(row[-1])
                    go = (row[-1] != u'-1')
                    del row[-1]
                    attr_train.append(row)
            label_train_arr = np.asarray(label_train)
        attr_train_arr = np.asarray(attr_train)
        break
    break

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

for arr in range(len(attr_train_arr)):
    newArr = le.fit_transform(attr_train_arr[arr])
    attr_train_arr[arr] = newArr

label_train_arr = map(float, label_train_arr)
for arr in attr_train_arr:
    arr = map(float, arr)
x = attr_train_arr
y = label_train_arr

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = .5)
print "after split"

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
#my_classifier = SGDClassifier()

from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier
my_classifier = PassiveAggressiveClassifier()

my_classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print "after fit"

predictions = my_classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: what line is causing the error?

Comment: You don't need to map to float, they are already float...you need to map them to uint32

Comment: the error occurs at the last line, where I predict the result with X_test. And I just realized my mistake with mapping to float! I'll fix it and update

Comment: the error does not go away although I changed it to uint32 and some other variations. any ideas?